# fast way to search for a set of words in a list of words python

Tags: python, string, search, nltk

I have a set of fixed words of size 20. I have a large file of 20,000 records, where each record contains a string and I want to find if any word from the fixed set is present in a string and if present the index of the word.

example

```
s1=set([barely,rarely, hardly])#( actual size 20) 

l2= =["i hardly visit", "i do not visit", "i can barely talk"] #( actual size 20,000)

def get_token_index(token,indx):
    if token in s1:
        return indx
    else:
        return -1


def find_word(text):
    tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    indexlist=[]
    for i in range(0,len(tokens)):
        indexlist.append(i)
    word_indx=map(get_token_index,tokens,indexlist)    
    for indx in word_indx:
        if indx !=-1:
           # Do Something with tokens[indx]
```

I want to know if there is a better/faster way to do it.

Comment: don't you have to call tokenize on the text?

Comment: For starters, there is absolutely no need to pre-build a list of indices, iterate over your items/indices using `enumerate`. Of course, this only cuts down on constant factors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggesting is only removing some glaring inefficiencies, but won't affect the overall complexity of your solution:

```
def find_word(text, s1=s1): # micro-optimization, make s1 local
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)    
    for i, word in in enumerate(tokens):
        if word in s1:
           # Do something with `word` and `i`
```

Essentially, you are slowing things down by using `map` when all you really need is a condition inside your loop body anyway... So basically, just get rid of `get_token_index`, it is over-engineered.

Comment: I thought map should be faster as it can do a parallel search on the list.

Comment: @AMisra what do you mean by "parallel search"? The built-in `map` is **not concurrent**

Comment: @AMisra anyway, that isn't the biggest issue, the biggest issue is that there is no need to make a pre-built list of indices, that is inefficient. That is why `range` and `enumerate` exists. Your `map`ing does nothing useful, and only adds an extra layer of function calls.

Comment: I thought map would be doing a parallel execution and hence I tried to add it. Is there a way to do parallel execution? I see multiprocessing library with pool function but it talks about _main_ check.

Comment: @AMisra In CPython you would have to use `multiprocessing`, which note, is essentially a wrapper around `subprocess`, and that is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension with a double for loop:

```
s1=set(["barely","rarely", "hardly"])

l2 = ["i hardly visit", "i do not visit", "i can barely talk"]

locations = [c for c, b in enumerate(l2) for a in s1 if a in b]
```

In this example, the output would be:

```
[0, 2]
```

However, if you would like a way of accessing the indexes at which a certain word appears:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for word in s1:
   for index, sentence in l2:
       if word in sentence:
           d[word].append(index)
```

Comment: This would be *slower* since it isn't checking if individual tokens are in the set, rather, it iterates over the set (red flag!) and checks if the set elements are in a string...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
strings = []
for string in l2:
    words = string.split(' ')
    for s in s1:
        if s in words:
            print "%s at index %d" % (s, words.index(s))
```

Comment: This will be *slower* since it iterates over the set, rather than checking membership in the set (the whole point of using the set...)

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest Way and Slightly More Efficient way would be using the Python Generator Function

index_tuple = list((l2.index(i) for i in s1 i in l2))

you can time it and check how efficiently this works with your requirement